# How to filter dropdownlist using another dropdownlist with angularJs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, filter

I've got 2 dropdownlist :

```
    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ServiceId, new SelectList(Model.ServiceList, "Id", "Title"), new { @class = "open" })
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceShareId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ServiceShareId, new SelectList(Model.ServiceShareList, "Id", "Title"), new { @class = "open" })
    </div>
```

I want to filter serviceshare values by service dropdownlist selected value. how to do?

Comment: can you please setup a basic plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the dropdownlist using angular pls find 
the below link for help.

http://plnkr.co/edit/n7TebC?p=preview